# Make multiple select menus jump to the first option

Tags: javascript

I've got 2 select menus. Example below.

How do I make both select menus jump to the first option when a button is clicked?

```
  <select class="personlist">
     <option value="One">One</option>
     <option value="Two">Two</option>
  </select>


  <select class="personlist">
     <option value="Ten">Ten</option>
     <option value="Eleven">Eleven</option>
  </select>
```

I came across similar posts while googling. But was not able to get it right.

```
document.getElementsByClassName('personlist').value=[0];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[getElementsByClassName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) returns an [HTMLCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection) object which is an array like object so you need to iterate over it and set the value

```js
function reset() {
  var els = document.getElementsByClassName('personlist');
  for (var i = 0; i < els.length; i++) {
    els[i].options[0].selected = true;
  }
}
```

```html
<select class="personlist">
  <option value="One">One</option>
  <option value="Two">Two</option>
</select>
<select class="personlist">
  <option value="Ten">Ten</option>
  <option value="Eleven">Eleven</option>
</select>
<button onclick="reset()">d</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you JQuery, you can use :

```
$('#select-a').click(function() {
  $('select.personlist').each(function() {  
    $(this).find('option').first().prop('selected', true)
  });
});
```